# Mounted directory not listing in terminal

Tags: macos, mount

Normally, I mount a remote drive to a directory on my Mac and it all works fine. I can open, edit and save my files in a text editor and they save back to the server, using the following to perform the mount:

`sshfs root@*.*.*.*:/var/www Documents/AWS/EC2/Linode`

This morning however, I get the following error:

```
fuse: bad mount point `Documents/AWS/EC2/Linode': Input/output error
```

On the terminal, I listed the content of `Documents/AWS/EC2` and Linode is missing. So, I decide to recreate it but the system complains it already exists.

I'm stumped. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution based on the following steps:

- Find the culprit sshfs process: `$ pgrep -lf sshfs`
- Kill it: `$ kill -9 <pid_of_sshfs_process>`
- Force unmount the "unavailable" directory: `umount -f Documents/AWS/EC2/Linode`

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Links can change so the site guidelines ask that answers do more than just post a link. See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review